# How is the Harris Corner detector derived from a Taylor Expansion?

Tags: taylor-expansion

It looks more like an assumption about local linearity of the function when the shifts `u` and `v` are small. This description of the Harris corner detector (used in computer vision) is as thorough as the [original paper](http://courses.daiict.ac.in/pluginfile.php/13002/mod_resource/content/0/References/harris1988.pdf), and yet I don't see how it relates to the Taylor Series expansion. Could someone connect the two? In the image below, $I_x$ refers to the derivative of I wrt x.

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Taylor in a mild form is invoked when $f(a+h)-f(a)$ is approximated as $hf'(a)+O(h^2)$, that is we use only the first term of the Taylor expansion and the estimate for the error term from Taylor's theorem; here in the form $I(x+u,v+u)-I(x,y)=uI_x(x,y)+vI_y(x,y)+O(u^2,v^2)$

Comment: Thanks! Could you relate what $O(u^2, v^2)$ means in terms of the image I added to the bottom of my question?

Comment: @RosePerrone In case you were still wondering after 9 years or if anyone runs into this. $O(u^2, v^2)$ is an upper bound. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/501735/why-do-we-use-big-oh-in-taylor-series).